# Search for the match in the middle of the string as well

Tags: php, regex, string

My regex:

`(?<=span class="ope">)[a-z0-9]+?\.(pl|com|net\.pl|tk|org|org\.pl|eu)|$(?=<\/span>)$`

At the moment, it does match only if the string is found on the beginning of the text, when its in the middle, it fails.

Eg.

`Something example.com` - fail

`example.com Something` - success (`example.com` found).

Is there any solution for this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=span class="ope">).*?([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.(pl|com|net\.pl|tk|org|org\.pl|eu)).*(?=<\/span>)
```

Test: http://www.regex101.com/r/wK0aA2

You're going to have to pull out group 1 rather than group 0 if you use this.

Comment: It does match everything between span tags.

Comment: @Scott You need to pull group 1 out of the regex, not the entire thing, as I indicated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tested solution:

```
(?<=span class="ope">).*?(?P<domain>\w+\.(?:pl|com|net\.pl|tk|org|org\.pl|eu)).*?(?=<\/span>)
```

it returns with the key `domain` your wanted domain. Try it here: http://www.regex101.com/r/mK1fP0

The problems where the two look behinds. The second one must be a lookahead instead. Also I inserted some `.*?` twice to match some stuff around the domain.

Comment: You used \w in your regex in place of my [A-Za-z0-9]. '\w' includes underscores, and almost all websites don't use underscores since it messes with IE cookies. 

He doesn't have a second look-behind. That's a look-ahead to check and see if </span> follows. You got confused when you saw `?=<` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?<=span class="ope">)[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*[a-z0-9]+?\.(pl|com|net\.pl|tk|org|org\.pl|eu)|$(?=<\/span>)$
```

Comment: Did you tested this one? http://regexr.com?3396c Working just like my regex `:p`.